# Can you explain me the REAL difference between asking for the best softwares, some good softwares or some softwares?

Tags: discussion

The formal difference is obvious, and there is a strong difference in many contexts, but I can't see any difference in a website like this.

**Infact what are you expecting to read as an answer to the following questions?**

- Can you list me the **best** software**s** to make a forensyc analysis tool that do X.?
- Can you list me some **good** software**s** to make a forensyc analysis tool that do X.? harddrive?
- Can you list **some softwares** to make a forensyc analysis tool that do X.?

**Please explain the concrete difference between the three answers. You can also provide some example.**

Do you think we really need to discourage people to use the word best for a merely formal purpose? Ok. If you think that please explain the reason and give a score to the importance YOU give to YOUR reason being conscious that OUR ideas are just relative and not absolute. Try to discuss them. Let's see why we believe they are right. Don't forget the final objective of this website. Please write down how do you think a guideline will help to achieve the final objective.

*I think there may be some confusion* between the concept of **using words as "good", "best"** and the less of **specification**. Saying "I look for the best graphic software" and "I look for the best software for doing this specific thing". **It's not the word good or best which makes the difference.**

**Instead I can understand to deny the use of *best* with the word *is***
I.e.

- Which **is** the **best** drug for...
- Which **are** the **best**
  drugs for...

Comment: Yupp, and here again: [Why question for Best tool is wrong, but for Good are ok?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/325/185) (see my answer over there). Maybe we decide for the best of these questions, and don't open other good ones? ;)

Comment: I think this question became more complete than it's duplicate. Can you give an evaluation of that?

Answer (score 8):

The problem with "Best" and "Good" is that they're worthless. But that they're worthless isn't necessarily an issue.

It is, without a doubt, that *anyone* seeking software is going to want the best solution for their problem. It is also our duty to strive to give people the *best* solutions out there, whether or not they explicitly ask them for it. So these are givens.

As such, the word "best" doesn't actually really impact anything. Judged solely on the word, there's no difference between the three questions. The problem with the word is whether or not the question is *reliant* on the word. When someone sees the word "best", the first thought that comes to mind should be "Best for what reasons?", and the question should explain these. In the past, this didn't happen very often. That's part of what led to much of the stigma out there for these words, is the lack of effort associated with them. Being exhausted of asking people "Best at *what*?" eventually led to exhaustion of the word entirely and major negative repercussions for just word choice. It's not just for the class of questions here - questions fine on other sites have been condemned as "premature optimization" and the like for using the word.

That's why most advice given to people who ask for the "best" of something, if people aren't trying to shut down the question entirely for being off-topic, the advice is to explain what is being sought out. Again, it's because "best" is a worthless classifier.

---

Ultimately I find that all three approaches listed are not useful, but also not much to make a fuss about. The final objective of this website is to provide  software to people who have problems they need to be solved. The real focus of any question is in the problem, and consequently the requirements needed of the software in terms of what it can do or what it needs and such. The rest, including things like even mentioning the words "I", "need", "a", "list", "of", "software", best or otherwise, in that order, are extraneous flavor. You need it to make your question sound right but it's just window dressing.

We already have enough problems with people being biased and flying off the handle at the mere mention of the word "best", I don't think it's healthy to continue that here. When you see the word "best", you look at the question and see if it meets our *actual* criteria as a site here. If they do, then we're good. If not, then focus on that.

Comment: I agree 100%. The problem with which I was complaining was about the prejudice against the word best! So I would put in the guidelines that NO one should be blamed for using the word "best" instead of "good". This is only making confusion. While we should always say "Best for what reasons?". I think it's is really important for this section but also for the others. **It's really important to clarify that there is no issue with using the word best (or the form of the question).** Many here were thinking the opposite.

Comment: To expand: I think people use the term best a lot here because they want multiple answers. Best implies there will be some contention in the answers, and there will be, which is why we have the voting system. They are anticipating this when they ask these question. Asking what is "A" text editor implies they will be happy with 1 answer. Indeed it is all window dressing.

Comment: @Enjabain: I completely agree. I would really like to stop the dispute against the usage of the word best or good. **These words are not changing the mean of a question in any way. I think this should be written in the guidelines. What do you think about?** Look at the first answer here: "http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/157/is-it-acceptable-to-use-best-in-a-question". It's blaming the word "best". And many users upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Best, good, etc. are subjective. Each person has a definition of what is the best for them. This was already [discussed here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/is-it-acceptable-to-use-best-in-a-question). The third one is not good either. A good one would be: *Hard drive forensic tool with X characteristic* or *Hard drive forensic tool that do X*.

You must write the category of what you are looking for (hard drive forensic tool) and some weird characteristic that you consider important. That would make an awesome question.

Comment: yes, but the problem is ONLY in the lack of specification of what you call "category of what you are looking for". Not in the usage of the word best. The three questions (I've edited now) lead exactly to the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

To put the cart before the horse, would you ask for...

- the worst X?
- a bad X?

Asking for "some": How many word processors do you need to write a letter? Does one ask "please only one answer"? Would you downvote subsequent answers? Do you thing if not expressively asked for, there wouldn't be more than one answer? I don't see the point here (but neither would I downvote/VTC a question just for that; I'd rather edit it).

Sorry if this sounds a bit snippy, but as [Braiam already mentioned](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/363/185#answer-364), this is already the 3<sup>rd</sup> question asking the very same. I'm already considering to ask whether we should merge them all into one.

PS: Don't feel offended, this is no personal attack. But IMHO it sometimes needs a drastic counter-example to make things clear ;)

Comment: The problem is that is really (let me use a strong word) silly to be worried about the use of the word "best". It's just window dressing. It doesn't add any that is opinionable to a question, it doesn't change the answer. I showed it very clearly with the three question example. There is absolutely no difference in asking for softwares that does x or asking for good softwares that does x or best softwares that does x. And also asking for the best software that does x could be a wrong word usage but.. doesn't change the answers in any way.

Comment: I fully agree. That's why I wrote I wouldn't downvote/VTC *just for that*, but rather edit (if I feel it necessary).