# Was this question "opinion-based" solely because of the word "best"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Recent question was closed for being opinion-based:  [Software for Floor Plan of School](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34421/software-for-floor-plan-of-school)

I'm not asking if best is always bad ([Is it acceptable to use 'best' in a question?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/is-it-acceptable-to-use-best-in-a-question?rq=1))

I'm asking about editing.  Couldn't the issue have been resolved with a simple edit?  What if instead of asking:

- "What is `the best` software for FREE that I can use to make a 2D floor plan of my school...",

the questioner had asked something like:

- "What is `some` software for FREE that I can use to make a 2D floor plan of my school..."

Would the question have been rendered valid?   As I read the guidelines and other questions, my opinion is "yes".

EDIT: **I clearly don't understand yet.   This question [Language for small, portable command line utilities](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34602/language-for-small-portable-command-line-utilities) is still unclosed.  I flagged it as opinion-based, but it's still there, so I must not understand the filtering criteria yet.  Can someone please enlighten me?**

Comment: I agree with Izzy's answer, there were more reasons besides primarily opinion-based. If you remove the word "best" and add more information that helps describe and help narrow down what you're looking for, I'm sure it'll be reopened in no time:)

Comment: @Tom thanks, but it's not my question.  I'm just trying to get a better handle on how things work here.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes, the phrase "what is the best" isn't really appropriate for this site:)

Comment: @Tom When I first saw the question, I knew that "best" would be an issue, but just translated it in my head.   If I'd had an answer, I'd have offered it.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, that's what we try to do whenever possible (and I've done that many times). But in this specific case, had I just erased the word "best" it would have been closed as "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad" – as it completely misses even basic criteria; see the comment I've left on it, even pointing to [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

- What OS should it run on?
- Is there any price limit?
- What features are considered essential, which are nice to haves, and are there any no-gos?

If the OP follows the advice given, edits the question, and improves it accordingly – I don't see a reason why it should not be reopened (to quicken that last step, I always accept "pings" – as I know we currently have only few users who could vote-to-reopen).

Comment: Thanks.   I bow to your superior understanding here, though it seems to me that two of those questions are actually answered in the OP, and for my money, if someone doesn't specify the operating system, they're usually talking about Windows.

Comment: While that might be (a. we don't always catch them all and b. the majority runs Windows), we discourage "laziness": If you expect help from people, give them all the relevant facts required for that. After all, you expect them spending their time on it to help you, so show some worthiness :) Additionally, on all SE sites "list type questions/answers" are discouraged. This would be one example which might end up in listing *all* "plan apps". Questions must be more specific than that.

Comment: ok, thanks.....